# Remover items duplicados en una colección SDT

Tags: genexus

Tengo un webpanel donde lleno un Grid sdt basada en algunas condiciones, cuestión que ese SDT me genera algunos items duplicados, hay alguna forma de "abrir" el SDT y quitar los items duplicados? No tengo mucha experiencia en SDT.

Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Para quitar un elemento de un SDT, deberías utilizar el método **Remove**:

```
&SDT.Remove(&Posicion)
```

Donde &Posicion debe ser la posición relativa del elemento en el SDT.
Por ejemplo:

```
&SDT.Remove(1)
```

te eliminaría el elemento que está en la posición 1. En tu caso, deberías primero identificar las posiciones de los elementos duplicados y luego eliminarlos utilizando este método.

Hay que tener en cuenta que al remover el elemento, se reindexan todas las posiciones a la siguiente ubicación disponible, esto es, si tienes un SDT del estilo:

```
Elemento 1(Posición 1), Elemento 2(Posición 2), Elemento 3(Posición 3),Elemento 4(Posición 4)...Elemento N-1(Posición N-1),Elemento N(Posición N)
```

Luego de ejecutar el Remove, por ejemplo del elemento 2( &SDT.Remove(2) ), el SDT quedará reindexado de esta manera:

```
Elemento 1(Posición 1), Elemento 3(Posición 2), Elemento 4(Posición 3), Elemento 5(Posición 4)...Elemento N-1(Posición N-2),Elemento N(Posición N-1)
```

Comment: como aporte nomás... Yo lo que hago en esos casos es ordenar la colección y a partir de ella crear una nueva colección, solamente insertando en la nueva si el elemento que estoy recorriendo es diferente al anterior.

Answer (score 0):

Con respecto a la reindexación, lo que hacemos nosotros es recorrer el SDT al revés:

```
For &i = &SDT.count to 1 step -1
    If &SDT.elemento = &condicion
        &SDT.Remove(&i)
    EndIf
EndFor
```